# Alarm and notification

Tags: android

I found this example of an alarm notification and I would just like to ask you to change two things.
This is MainActivity:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (129600000), pendingIntent);
     }
```

And this is MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  CharSequence from = "Locali Torino";
  CharSequence message = "Visita le serate!";
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0);

  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.disco,
    "Visita le serate!", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  nm.notify(1, notif);
 }
}
```

In this way, when I launch my app, now I see the notification but I would like to see it do so only after "x" milliseconds.
And then I want to know how to launch the MainActivity clicking on the notification.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call setRepeatingAlarm() with some delay. From service or from activity use e.g. Handler and post a runnable to it with small delay. If you are in activity, dont't forget to remove post action within your lifecycle methods, e.g. onStop(). If you want to make some action when user click on notification, edit `contentIntent` in your MyAlarmService.

E.g.

```
    Intent action = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    action, 0);
```

Comment: I did not understand where I need to enter that part of the code

Comment: Check MyAlarmService code. You have there Pending intent named contentIntent where you put an empty intent, which does nothing ofc.

Comment: ok but in this way the notification is automatically deleted once?

Comment: Of course. It will create a new one once alarm call MyAlarmService again.

Comment: Thank you!! but how can I use delay ThraedSleep?

Comment: See how to you Handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html. Don't try to sleep main thread.